# Is it ideal to use CSS3 even though it's not supported in all browsers?

Tags: css

I started a new web project today, and having never used CSS3 (always used CSS 2, but have not done web development for 1.5 years) I decided to use it for this project.

Straight off the bat I had issues. I tried to implement a linear gradient, and seen it needs 6 implementations for different browsers - including latest browsers.

Is it too early to start using CSS3 projects, it just seems like so much code bloat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you just have to make a decision if you want your page to look the exact same in every browser (hint: [you don't](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/)). You can check support of CSS3 features here: http://html5please.com/.

You could also try to use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) and functions to abstract away the double / triple / sextuple implementations for you.

Comment: I have never heard of SASS and LESS. Wow, this is an eye opener. What was meant by your hint? Why wouldn't I want my page to look the same in all browsers (obviously excluding mobile/tablet)

Comment: Well, there are so many browsers which differ so wildly in their support of features, you have to decide how much trouble you want to go through to support all of them. For example: rounded corners are a piece of cake to do in moder browsers, not so much in older ones. You could either have them show as square corners or jump through hoops (using libraries and a bunch of extra code) to make them look the same.

Comment: Ah, yeah I get what you mean.

Comment: Cool, good luck with your project! By the way, you can find some great LESS mixing (functions) here: http://lesselements.com/ and here: http://lesshat.com/.